# EntityFramework 6: How do I find a previously found record?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, find, entity-framework-6

If I find a record in EntityFramework 6 (ADO) and then try to find that record again, the Find method returns 0. Here's an example:

```
var db3 = new IMS();

db3.TabModuleSettings.Find(973, "ShowSoldOut"); //Local.Count=1
db3.TabModuleSettings.Local.Clear(); //Local.Count=0

db3.TabModuleSettings.Find( 142, "AllowIndex" ); //Local.Count=1
db3.TabModuleSettings.Local.Clear(); //Local.Count=0

db3.TabModuleSettings.Find(973, "ShowSoldOut"); //Local.Count=0
db3.TabModuleSettings.Local.Clear(); //Local.Count=0

db3.TabModuleSettings.Find( 142, "AllowIndex" ); //Local.Count=0
```

How do I find a previously found record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things to keep in mind:

- If you do `Local.Clear()` the entities in the `Local` collection are marked for deletion. So the entity with key values `(973, "ShowSoldOut")` is still present in the context's cache, but it's state is `Deleted`. (Same for the one with `(142, "AllowIndex")`, later).
- `DbSet.Find` looks for entities in the context's cache first and then, when not found, it looks in the database. If the entity is found in the cache, but is deleted, EF figures it shouldn't be there anymore and it doesn't return it.

I don't know why you do these `Local.Clear()` calls, but I hope you realize now that it's statement to use with care.

The right way to clear the cache is by detaching the entities, for instance for one `Local` collection:

```
foreach (var x in db3.TabModuleSettings.Local.ToList())
{
    Entry(x).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
}
```

(although this will not detach deleted entities).

Or the entire cache:

```
foreach (var entry in db3.ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
    entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
}
```

(will also detach deleted entities).

Or all entities of a specific type (including deleted):

```
foreach (var entry in db3.ChangeTracker.Entries<TabModuleSetting>())
{
    entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
}
```

Although normally you shouldn't have to do this. It's usually better to dispose a context and create a new one if you want to refresh entities.

Comment: So, how do I force a database lookup rather than a cache lookup? Or, how do I empty the cache?

The .Clear was meant to empty the result set. There are quite a few things that happen in between the .Find statements.

Comment: Added some more info.

Comment: OK. I thought there would be a performance hit on disposing and reinitializing the IMS class. The first time, it takes around 15 seconds. But,
db3.Dispose() db3=new IMS() does not seem to cause a performance issue and it handles what I need handled.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty. All I needed to do was this:

db3.TabModuleSettings = new IMS().TabModuleSettings;

That's it.

Comment: I think that's what I said in the last line of my answer. And I also explain what's the problem with your first approach.

Comment: Well. not really. You indicated I should dispose the entire context, losing any other entities that may exist. I still need to keep some of my previous finds. My way,  I'm just disposing a selected entity. db3 is my entire context and I don't want to lose the entire context.

Comment: Ah, is that what you do? I'd strongly advice against that. You replace an entire DbSet while the context's change tracker still contains information of the entities in the previous set. This is a whole range of strange bugs waiting to happen. If you remove selected entities, you *have* to detach the entities you want to get rid of. Internally, EF will keep its change tracker (and relationship manager) in sync. I revised my answer to include that scenario.

Comment: Oh, wow. Ok, I did not know that. I thought re-initializing the entity would clear the change tracker for that entity. The change tracker belongs to the context only and not the entities. So, your third scenario seems to be what I need. And that makes more sense with DbContext.SaveChanges(). Great. I will give this a whirl.